# PHP Mysql DISTINCT Column Where current date

Tags: php, mysql

Just Wanted us to DISTINCT a Column and same time short into Current Date

Table contains ref,joined   then now need to short by joined date = Current date

Joined = 2019-12-21 15:10:53;

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ref FROM users where joined = Current date ";
```

how write this query help us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  `NOW()`

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ref FROM users where joined = NOW() ";
```

also you can use `group by`

```
$sql = "SELECT ref FROM users where joined = NOW() group by ref  ";
```

Comment: also CURDATE() ,DATE(NOW()) depending upon your date field

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by to get distinct rows. If you need all records joined today, you can use below query.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT ref FROM users where joined>='$date 00:00:00' and joined<='$date 23:59:59' group by ref"
```

I hope it will works for you.

Comment: unfortunately data getting from all dates

Answer (score -1):

/*Here we go..!*/

$jdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(ref) FROM users where joined = '$jdate' ";

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: Thank You  Strawberry for correcting me.!  DISTINCT is a statement.